# How to populate spring form on selecting radio button

Tags: spring, radio-button

I have spring form. And I want to populate the form on clicking the radio button next to Employee listing , so that when clicked it should fill the form with data related to that employee in form fields.

Comment: I/We don`t know anything about the "radio button next to Employee listing" - your question does NOT descipe your code and probelm in details, so that it is very hard to answer anything usefull.

Comment: I can suggest two variant: first when onClick happens you can reload your page and rebuild your jsp, second when onClick happens you can perform an AJAX request and receive only form data. But as Ralph mentioned you should specify your requirements in details.